# Title attribute on circle overlays

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I understand that `google.maps.Marker` can have a `title` set to them in their options, can the same be done for `google.maps.Circle`?

I've tried just setting `title` on the `google.maps.CircleOptions` object, but that doesn't seem to do anything.

Is there a way I can give the circle overlays a title? I imagine there is, as when you hover over a circle, the cursor is changed to `pointer` so there must be some kind of detection there. I don't want to make my own custom tooltip and attach it to the hover event on the circle, I want to use the browser's built in title hover.

Circles:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Circles

CircleOptions object: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#CircleOptions

Comment: I'm answering the same now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not currently possible to add a title to a circle. As you can see from the [CircleOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#CircleOptions), it doesn't list 'title' as a option that you can use.

A work around could be to listen to the mousemove event on the circle then to show your own title as a custom [OverlayView](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#OverlayView)